# C2DM VB.Net code snippet returning Error=MissingRegistration

Tags: android, vb.net, android-c2dm

I am using the tutorial laid out here http://www.androidsnippets.com/vbnet-server-side-code-to-send-c2dm-messages to attempt to send a message to my device. I have requested a device ID and placed that string in the RegID String.

I receive a (what looks like a) GUID for the googleAuthToken successfully, but when the rest of the code executes, the response I get is Error=MissingRegistration. What exactly am I missing to implement C2DM from a server via VB.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, naturally as soon as I ask, the answer presents itself: durring the copying process

```
    body += "collapse_key=nothing"
    body += "&data.burst_id=" + "12345"
    body += "&registration_id=" + RegID
```

became

```
    body += "collapse_key=RDMS"
    body += "&amp;data.burst_id=" + "12345"
    body += "&amp;registration_id=" + RegID
```

So replacing the & with the standard & caused me to get a message id back.